# Prevent commit when gitlab-CI pipeline fail

Tags: git, testing, gitlab, push, gitlab-ci

**Is there a way to prevent a push to gitlab if the pipeline fail?**

Here's a gitlab-ci.yml sample with multiple jobs. This pipeline is triggered on every push.

If one of the job failed  I don't want my code to be pushed on my repository. (I know this feature exist for pull request).

```
image: node:9.4.0

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

stages:
    - lint
    - test

lint:
  stage: lint
  script:
   - npm run lint

test:
  stage: test
  script:
   - npm run test
```

Comment: Where do you *run* your tests? How does your code get to the CI system?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry Simon - this is not how this is supposed to work. You need the stuff in the repo so the pipeline can run.

You should use a branching flow, where you only allow successful builds/merge requests to be merged against develop/master, so you don't have to care if failing code is added in the repo. Your main branches always stay clean. You can enforce this behavior by only allowing merges against develop/master (protected branches) and not allow direct pushes.

For simpler things you can use pre-commit hooks, with only allow pushing if, for example, npm run lint succeeds. But, running a whole pipeline is too much for a pre-commit-hook (it may work, but it's not best practice).